# Show that the vectors form a basis for $R^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Show that the vectors $\alpha_1 = (1, 0, 1)$, $\alpha_2 = (1, 2, 1)$, $\alpha_3 = (0, -3, 2)$ form a basis for $R^3$. Is it enough to show that the vectors are linearly independent?

Comment: You may also need to prove these span $\mathbb R^3$ but I think there's a theorem to show that it is equivalent to linear independence for 3 vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

If the vector space has dimension $n$, then every set of $n$ independent vectors is a basis